# Filter within groups where x first exceeds y

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr

I have a database consisting of

- neighborhood IDs for home neighborhoods (id_h),
- block IDs for home blocks (`blk_h`,
- a sub-geography of neighborhoods),
- work blocks (`blk_w`),
- the flow of commuters between the two (`Flow`),
- the median commuter per home neighborhood (`Med_C`), and
- the cumulative worker flow by home neighborhood (`CumFlow`).

The data is sorted by distance between `blk_h` and `blk_w` (descending), grouped by `id_h`. I need to subset the data to extract the case for each home neighborhood where `CumFlow` FIRST equals or exceeds `Med_C`.

I've tried a variety of dplyr functions and cannot get it to work. Here's an example:

```
df <- data.frame(
  id_h=c("A","A","A","A","B","B","B"),
  blk_h=c("A1","A1","A2","A2","B1","B2","B2"),
  blk_w=c("W1","W2","W3","W3","W1","W2","W2"),
  dist=c(4.3,5.6,7.0,8.7,5.2,6.5,6.8),
  Flow=c(3,6,3,7,5,4,2),
  CumFlow=c(3,9,12,19,5,9,11),
  Med_C=c(10,10,10,10,6,6,6)
)
df
```

I need for this to return a table like this:

```
id_h  blk_h  blk_w  dist  Flow  CumFlow  Med_C
A     A2     W3     7.0   3     12       10
B     B2     W2     6.5   4     9        6
```

And here are some of the things I've tried to make this happen:
Attempt #1

```
library(dplyr)
df.g <- group_by(df, id_h) 
df.g2 <- filter(df.g, CumFlow == which.min(CumFlow >= Med_C))
```

Attempt #2

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .SD[which.min(CumCount >= Med_C)], by = id_h]
```

Attempt #3

```
library(dplyr)
test <- df %>% group_by(id_h) %>% filter(min(CumFlow) >= Med_C)
```

I think I am misunderstanding how to use the `which.min` function. Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Yeah, it's confusion of `which.min`, which finds the first minimum instead of the first true value; and if all values are the same, returns 1. You can use `head(which(CumFlow >= Med_C), 1)` instead of which.min here.

Comment: @majom I mentioned this the last time too: don't edit tags into questions based on what the answers use.

Comment: @ Frank: The question in this case asks specifically how to to it with `data.table`. Thus the tag is legimate. See Attempt "#2 `library(data.table); setDT(df)[, .SD[which.min(CumCount >= Med_C)], by = id_h]`". For general guidelines on tagging see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37672/when-should-you-edit-tags

Comment: Wow, those are very good `CumFlow` numbers

Comment: @majom No, they did not ask how to do it with data.table. They showed an attempt. Actually, I edited in the library data.table command so that their attempt made sense. I am familiar with the guidance on meta. In fact, someone (I think it was Matt Dowle..?) was editing in the data.table tag back in the day as you are doing now and was told not to (not sure why I can't find the meta trail). The question should represent how the OP was thinking about it. Same reason you don't edit the title to reflect the answer.

Comment: @ Frank: Ok. Got it - makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two `filter` calls can solve this.

Using `group_by` to work within each `id_h`, the first `filter` returns a `data.frame` with all rows where the `CumFlow` is greater than or equal to the `Med_C`.  The second `filter` returns, within each `id_h`, the row with the lowest `CumFlow`.  This only works because the data is sorted.  To make the work more robust you may consider adding a call to `arrange` after the call to `group_by`.

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(
  id_h    = c("A","A","A","A","B","B","B"),
  blk_h   = c("A1","A1","A2","A2","B1","B2","B2"),
  blk_w   = c("W1","W2","W3","W3","W1","W2","W2"),
  dist    = c(4.3,5.6,7.0,8.7,5.2,6.5,6.8),
  Flow    = c(3,6,3,7,5,4,2),
  CumFlow = c(3,9,12,19,5,9,11),
  Med_C   = c(10,10,10,10,6,6,6)
)
df

df %>%
group_by(id_h) %>%
filter(CumFlow >= Med_C) %>%
filter(CumFlow == min(CumFlow))
```

Comment: This did it!! Many, many thanks. I get it now, that I needed two filters.

Answer (score 3):

Two things:

- you need `slice` (which takes an index) instead of `filter` (which takes booleans), and
- since the usage of `which.min` is odd (it returns the index of the first value equal to the minimum, and you have a lot of 1s and 0s), you actually need `which.max`, as you want the first value of `1`, i.e. `TRUE`,

so

```
df %>% group_by(id_h) %>% 
  slice(which.max(CumFlow >= Med_C))
## Source: local data frame [2 x 7]
## Groups: id_h [2]
## 
##     id_h  blk_h  blk_w  dist  Flow CumFlow Med_C
##   <fctr> <fctr> <fctr> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>
## 1      A     A2     W3   7.0     3      12    10
## 2      B     B2     W2   6.5     4       9     6
```

Comment: `which.max` when the condition never holds will return 1/first row, which may or may not be what the OP wants in that case.

Comment: @Frank Fair point. I'd probably use `df %>% group_by(id_h) %>% filter(CumFlow >= Med_C) %>% slice(1)` for clarity, honestly.

Comment: Yeah, just depends if you want to drop the group if it fails to meet that criterion or not. I'd maybe `slice( which(CumFlow >= Med_C)[1] )`, which I think would give an NA row.

Comment: It may not be an issue if it's a median and cumulative count of the same quantity, but I'm a little unclear on the units.

Comment: Yep, this approach also works. Can you help me understand this which.max command though? I knew my filter problem had to do with the indexing, but why am I using which.max, and what does the [1] at the end of this code do? I'm what I'd call R proficient, but am trying hard to get better.

Comment: The units for both are workers. There are cases where the cumulative count and the median are the same number, in other cases it's off by 0.5, and in about 10% of my cases it's off by more than 0.5. In any case, I didn't get any NAs.

Comment: `which.min`/`which.max` looks for the minimum value[s]. If there's more than one, it returns the first. You're passing it a bunch of `TRUE`s and `FALSE`s, which when coerced to numbers become `1` and `0` respectively, so `which.min` will return the first `FALSE`, and `which.max` will return first `TRUE`.

Comment: And the `[1]` in Frank's returns the first value returned by the `which` call, which will return `integer(0)` if it's never true, and thus introduce an `NA`. The larger concern was whether it's possible for `CumFlow` to never meet the condition, i.e. be as big as `Med_C`.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with dplyr like this

```
df %>% group_by(id_h) %>% 
  mutate(times_greater = cumsum(CumFlow >= Med_C)) %>% 
  filter(times_greater == 1)
```

Comment: I assumed cumulative flow always was rising, and med_c was constant, but it was unclear from the question.

Comment: I get the right number of rows with this solution. So I think both this and Peter's dplyr solution both work. Thanks!

Comment: It is commuter flow, but I did calculate the cumulative, so help identify the blk_h and blk_w pair that contained the median worker.

Answer (score 2):

A `data.table` solution would look like this:

```
# Load package
library(data.table)

# Setup data
df <- data.table(
  id_h=c("A","A","A","A","B","B","B"),
  blk_h=c("A1","A1","A2","A2","B1","B2","B2"),
  blk_w=c("W1","W2","W3","W3","W1","W2","W2"),
  dist=c(4.3,5.6,7.0,8.7,5.2,6.5,6.8),
  Flow=c(3,6,3,7,5,4,2),
  CumFlow=c(3,9,12,19,5,9,11),
  Med_C=c(10,10,10,10,6,6,6))

 # Calculation
 df.out <- df[CumFlow >= Med_C, .SD[1], by = id_h]
```

`df.out` looks like that:

```
> df.out
   id_h blk_h blk_w dist Flow CumFlow Med_C
1:    A    A2    W3  7.0    3      12    10
2:    B    B2    W2  6.5    4       9     6
```

Comment: It tells me the by= is an unused argument

Comment: Did you setup the data like I did, i.e. using `df <- data.table(...` instead of `df <- data.frame(...`.

Comment: Derp. Right. That was it.